# Creating a weighted network based on common contributions

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(V1 = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","A"),
                     V3 = c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Y"),
                     V2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
atest <- aggregate(V2~V1+V3,data=test,FUN=length)

to = unique(atest$V3)

el <- data.frame (a = NA, b = NA, weight = NA)
for (y in (1:length(to))) {
  curto <- to[y]
  curpo <- atest[atest$V3 == curto,]
  result <- expand.grid(a=unique(curpo$V1),b=unique(curpo$V1))
  result <- result[result$a != result$b,]
  curpo$V3 <- NULL
  result <- merge(result,curpo,by.x=c("a"),by.y=c("V1"),all.x=T)
  if (length(result)==0) {
    result = data.frame (a = NA, b = NA, weight = NA)
  } else {
    result = data.frame(a = result[,1], b = result[,2], weight = result[,3])
  }
  el = rbind(el,result)
  cat(paste(y,"\r\n"))
}

el <- na.omit(el)
el <- aggregate(weight~a+b,data=el,FUN=sum)
```

I want to build a network based on the activity that people have in X and Y. I can do it using a for loop that looks on each set of items on V3, however, that would be slow. The V2 column is just use for the aggregate function and it has no other purpose. The outcome that I want to get should look  like this:

```
  A - B - 4
  A - C - 4
  B - C - 2
  B - A - 2
  C - A - 2
  C - B - 2
```

Comment: can you help explain how the outcome is derived, e.g. how to arrive at "A - B - 4" ?

Comment: Unique combinations for V1 items are being generated for each V3 (X and Y). Then in the new dataset of unique combinations, for each V1 the V2 values are added to that table. Finally, results for X and Y are aggregated using the sum function. Does this help?

Comment: I get that for a single value of V1 (e.g. A - 4), but how does the second value of V1 (i.e. B in A - B -4) come into play? Or did I misunderstand that?

Otherwise, am I correct to understand that your desired outcome can actually be summarised into 3 lines: A - 4, B - 2, C - 2 (i.e. omitting the middle column) ?

Comment: @Michael it will be clear to paste your `for-loop` code :)

Comment: I just updated the post with the for loop included that produces the result. The problem would be simple if I had to calculate combinations based on V1 alone. But because I have to calculate for each value in V3, it is complicated. I couldn't come up with an alternative to the for loop.